# Java sending html multipart email and MS Outlook

Tags: java, email

When application sends html multipart email, outlook does not render correctly.  We are using spring **org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator**
and **org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl**

It renders email as text and looks something like this...

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
                boundary="----=_Part_87_599524958.1351800925134"

------=_Part_87_599524958.1351800925134
Content-Type: multipart/related; 
                boundary="----=_Part_88_222697382.1351800925134"

------=_Part_88_222697382.1351800925134
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
                boundary="----=_Part_89_1958386200.1351800925181"

------=_Part_89_1958386200.1351800925181
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

...
... <<< some text here >>>
...


------=_Part_89_1958386200.1351800925181
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

...
... << here it prints html text >>
...
...
```

Comment: Do other email clients render it correctly?  Try sending the message to gmail or some other client. Also, you can try examining the exact content of a multipart email that outlook does render correctly.

Comment: Yes, local outlook 2010 it is rendering.

Comment: So in outlook 2010 it renders correctly and in some other version it does not? Your answer is unclear.  In what other non-Microsoft mail clients have you tested your software's output?  Is this an outlook problem or a java spring api problem?